# Static base class attribute with different values in subclasses

Tags: c++, inheritance, static, polymorphism

I have different objects that can be produced. Each object type has different costs. I want to check whether the user can afford a specific object **BEFORE** creating it. The following approach does not respect this requirement:

```
class Costs {
public:
    int oneCost, anotherCostAttribute; // Actual values for both attribute may differ for the objects
}

class Object {
public:
    virtual Costs getCosts() = 0;
} 

class Object_A : public Object {
    // implement getCosts (always the same for all A's)
}

class Object_B : public Object {
    // implement getCosts (always the same for all B's)
}

// Usage:
// I would have to create a specific object just to check the costs:
Object* pObj = new Object_A();
if(avilableResources >= pObj->getCosts()) {
   // Store object, otherwise delete it
}
```

My second idea was some kind of base class which offers a virtual static function, but this is not possible with C++:

```
class Object {
public:
    virtual static Costs getCosts() = 0;
}
```

Just using a static *Costs* attribute would not allow to distinguish sub class costs:

```
class Object {
public:
    static Costs m_costs; // All objects (A,B,...) would cost the same
}
```

What would be a proper way to directly associate the costs to the objects?

Comment: Does your getCosts() function access any other members in Object or its children? Or is it just a getter for the Costs member?

Comment: It is just a getter which is basically a class with some integers, please see my edit that I just added

Answer (score 2):

You could provide this information through a template:

```
template <typename CostsT>
struct Object {
  static CostsT m_costs;
};
```

For example you could have a base `Costs` class:

```
struct Costs {
  virtual int oneCost() = 0;
  virtual int anotherCost() = 0;
};
```

And you declare your objects with specific types of subclasses of `Costs`:

```
struct Costs_A: Costs {
  virtual int oneCost() override { return 1; }
  virtual int anotherCost() override { return 2; }
};
using Object_A = Object<Costs_A>;
```

That way you can retrieve the specific Costs instance before deciding whether to instantiate Object_A:

```
Costs costsA = Object_A::m_costs;
```

Answer (score 1):

A static function cannot be virtual, but can still be overriden. Simply the version being used does not depend of the actual class of the object but only of the declared class of the pointer used to access it.

But this could be used to do a test before creating an object:

```
class ObjectA: public Object {
    ...
public:
    static int getCost() {
        return 10;
    }
    ...
};

class ObjectB: public Object {
    ...
public:
    static int getCost() {
        return 20;
    }
    ...
};
```

Then:

```
Object *pObj;
if (availableResources >= ObjectA::getCost()) {  // correctly calls the expected function
    pObj = new ObjectA();
}
```

You must just know that `pObj->getCost()` will return the `Object` version independantly of the actual class - you could even never declare `getCost` in `Object` class to raise a compile time error if you try to use it.